# need to call a method for string parameters in the function

Tags: c#, function, methods

```
public static void ClickOnSubLevelMenus(IWebDriver driver, string menu1, string menu2)
    {
        //click on the first menu 
        Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu1);
        //click on the second menu
        Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu2 );
    }
```

If I have three strings of menus as paramters, i need to call that method 3 times. What's the best way to do it instead of doing like this.

```
//click on the first menu 
Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu1);
//click on the second menu
Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu2);
//click on the third menu
Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `params string[]`:

```
public static void ClickOnSubLevelMenus(IWebDriver driver, params string[] menus)
{
    foreach(string menu in menus)
        Utility.ClickOnASpanText(driver, menu);
}
```

You can call it in this way:

```
ClickOnSubLevelMenus(driver, "menu1", "menu2", "menu3");
```

or in this:

```
string[] allMenus = { "menu1", "menu2", "menu3" };
ClickOnSubLevelMenus(driver, allMenus);
```